# Javascript/jQuery get true width and position of float affected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, width, floating

Is it possible to get the width (using javascript or jQuery) of a float-affected element? When text is being pushed over due to a floating image is it possible to get its position and true width? I have attached an image to explain better.

Code example,

```
<div>
    <img style="...float: left"/>
    <h1>A title!</h1>
    <p>Text!</p>
    <h1>New header added.</h1>
</div>
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0PVZ.jpg)

I need to find the width starting from the arrow, (the gray box is the image)(the dotted line is the width according to Firefox inspect mode).

I would like to avoid changing all the elements display types if possible.
Thank you!

Comment: You don't actually need to "find the width" as much as "place the <p> tag to the right of the image", isn't that your desired solution?

Comment: Yea that could be a solution, however I think that would involve changing all the elements css. I would rather calculate the width without having to make an modifications to the html or css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the "full width" is exactly the true width.

You can watch this picture, it can help you understand why the true width and true position of the affected element is the way firefox tells you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB5Ds.png

To get the width of inline text where it's pushed right by the float image, there's no good way except using the full width minus the float image's width.

```
var w = $('p').width() 
        - $('img').width() 
        - $('img').css('margin-left').replace("px", "")
        - $('img').css('margin-right').replace("px", "")
        - $('img').css('padding-left').replace("px", "")
        - $('img').css('padding-right').replace("px", "")
        - $('img').css('border-left-width').replace("px", "")
        - $('img').css('border-right-width').replace("px", "");
```

Comment: I figured I might have to do something like that, thanks Phoenix. I ended up making a loop which looks through all the elements, detects if they are actually beside the image (using position and height) then calculates the width I am looking for using image width. It seems to work reliably, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but I had a similar problem and came up with a solution which (so far) seems to work in all instances of this issue.  I like this solution because as far as I can tell, it works independent of the floating element - all you need is the element whose true width/position you want to get, nothing more.  I've done it in pure Javascript for speed purposes, but it can easily be streamlined with jQuery and a separate CSS Stylesheet if you so choose.

```
//Get the rendered bounding box for the content of any HTMLElement "el"
var getLimits = function(el) {
    //Set a universal style for both tester spans; use "!important" to make sure other styles don't mess things up!
    var testerStyle = 'width: 0px!important; overflow: hidden!important; color: transparent!important;';

    //Create a 'tester' span and place it BEFORE the content
    var testerStart = document.createElement('SPAN');
    testerStart.innerHTML = '|';
    var testerFloat = ' float: left!important;';
    testerStart.setAttribute('style', testerStyle + testerFloat);

    //Insert testerStart before the first child of our element
    if (el.firstChild) {
        el.insertBefore(testerStart, el.firstChild);
    } else {
        el.appendChild(testerStart);
    }

    //Create a 'tester' span and place it AFTER the content
    var testerEnd = document.createElement('SPAN');
    testerEnd.innerHTML = '|';
    testerFloat = ' float: right!important;';
    testerEnd.setAttribute('style', testerStyle + testerFloat);
    el.appendChild(testerEnd);

    //Measure the testers
    var limits = {
        top: testerStart.offsetTop,
        bottom: testerEnd.offsetTop + testerEnd.offsetHeight,
        left: testerStart.offsetLeft,
        right: testerEnd.offsetLeft
    }

    //Remove the testers and return
    el.removeChild(testerStart);
    el.removeChild(testerEnd);
    return limits;
};
```

So, in your case, the code would just be:

```
var paragraphBoundingBox = getLimits($('div>p').get(0));
```

A couple things to note:

1) The float direction would be reversed if you are using an RTL language

2) All of the four edge positions in the output object are relative to the el.offsetParent - use [this handy](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) function can find their positions relative to the document.